# Vim: sorting with levels

Tags: vim

I have the following file with Markdown markup:

```
* [B](B)
  * b
  * c
* [C](C)
* [A](a)
  * a
```

I try to sort it and get the following result:

```
* [A](a)
  * a
* [B](B)
  * b
  * c
* [C](C)
```

It is necessary to sort only the main levels, and sub-levels must follow the main levels, i.e., stay at the levels where they were. The first thing that comes to mind is of course `:sort`; but unfortunately this will also sort the sub-levels. We will get:

```
  * a
  * b
  * c
* [A](a)
* [B](B)
* [C](C)
```

Are there any tricks or plugins for this kind of sorting? Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach for this class of problems is to inline each block, then sort them, and then "de-inline" them back to their original state.

**First step**: inline each block.

We do this by replacing each EOL followed by SPACE-SPACE-STAR with some fancy symbol unlikely to be found in our document:

```
:%s/\n\(  \*\)/§\1
```

Which gives us the following:

```
* [B](B)§  * b§  * c
* [C](C)
* [A](a)§  * a
```

**Second step**: sort the buffer.

We simply use `:help :sort`:

```
:sort
```

to obtain this:

```
* [A](a)§  * a
* [B](B)§  * b§  * c
* [C](C)
```

**Third step**: revert each "block" to its initial state.

We do this by reverting the substitution above with another, much simpler, one:

```
:%s/§/\r
```

which gives us the desired outcome:

```
* [A](a)
  * a
* [B](B)
  * b
  * c
* [C](C)
```

A couple of notes:

- The exact pattern to use in the first substitution depends on the exact structure of your document. That part is, IMO, too highly contextual to be generalisable.
- `§` is just an example, use whatever symbol you want.